# Ubuntu 22.04 does not open applications, shows black screen window insted

Tags: bug-reporting, 22.04

I am new to ubuntu,

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from 20.04 LTS. I am having a issue with the new version.

When I open any of the applications expect ubuntu's system softwares, it just opens a black window and the app it self does not start.

Can someone please help, how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using an NVidia graphics card?

Comment: On the log in screen, before entering your password, click the cog icon and select "Ubuntu on Xorg". Try if that works better. You can also revert to the default session on Wayland (session "Ubuntu") the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not download any package. It is simple to resolve this problem following these steps.

1. Just upgrade or install ubuntu 22.04.
2. After you setup everything then log out.
3. After log out u will see your profile name to login again just click on it.
4. After clicking on profile password screen will arrive on that screen on right bottom corner you will se a settings icon just click on it.
5. In `Settings`, you will see by default it is selected *ubuntu*. Just see another option named *ubuntu in xorg*. Click on it or tick it after that type your password and done now you will not face any problem enjoy.

100% working solution.

Comment: I had the same issue, upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04. Was getting a black window from gparted and Firefox would not display. The Ubuntu in xorg option sorted it for me. Many thanks.

Comment: After switched to xorg, black screen is appeared on my system. Back to Wayland is ok but mate-terminal so bad