# Ubuntu default apps show up as black windows when using virtualization

Tags: 22.04, bug-reporting

**This is not a duplicate of [Default apps black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942415/default-apps-black-screen)**

I'm trying out Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with virtualization via UTM on an M1 Mac.

Default apps like Settings, Software Updater and even the Installer simply show up as black windows while non-default ones like Firefox work fine.

[Screenshot of the Ubuntu Installer as a black window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPWOo.jpg)

How do I go about fixing this? I haven't installed Ubuntu properly yet so I don't have access to the login screen where I can switch to xorg as per this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404914/1671477)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue with the graphics drivers. Go to your VM Setting -> Display. Then Change `Emulated Display Card` to virtio-ramfb or virtio-gpu-pci. For more details you can read this github issues https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/4090

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! I switched to virtio-ramfb and the problem disappeared. Unfortunately, don't have enough Reputation to upvote but this is the answer

Comment: You're welcome. No problem glad to help.